# How to start up Aptana Studio 3 on Mac OSX as root?

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, aptana, pydev

I installed Aptana Studio 3 on my Mac Book OS 10.6 as a non-root user.  My goal is to develop Python applications with Aptana Studio.  Seeing its potential, I decided to use Aptana / Pydev to play around with networking applications.  To my dismay I could not open TCP ports.  Regardless of what I do, I could not get Aptana to open as root.  The first thing I would notice is the default workspace is in the nonroot user's home directory.  To verify, i.e. os.getuid() is always non-zero.  At soon as I run test-script.py within Aptana that attempts to open TCP ports, it would run into permission errors.  However I have no problem whatsoever launching "sudo python2.7 test-script.py" from terminal shell.  I've tried the following methods to no avail:

1. After gaining root access "su", then "open /Applications/Aptana\ Studio\ 3/.... .app".  "import os", "os.getuid()" results in nonzero.
2. After gaining root access "su", then "hdiutil mount Aptana_Studio_3_Setup.dmg", and "open /Volume/Aptana\ Studio\ 3/.....app".  "import os", "os.getuid()" results in nonzero.
3. Noticing that "env" output "USER=nonroot", I tried "export USER=root" after "su", and repeated steps 1 and 2.  Same results.
4. After "sudo chown root test-script.py", and "sudo chmod a+s test-script.py", repeated steps 1 and 2.  Same results.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was having used the /usr/bin/open command to open the application.
If I had typed "sudo /Applications/MyAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp" it would have worked automatically and seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: There is no need to apologize! :)